# How to use where conditon based on string values in a pandas dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

How do I use multiple conditions to correct values in my dataframe

I want to change

- Apple = Fruit
- Potato = Veg

My data frame is like this

```
      Item      Category
      Apple     Freshco
      Potato    Sobeys
      Orange    Fruit
      Banana    Fruit
```

I want to change the two categories so the dataframe is like this

```
      Item      Categroy
      Apple     Fruit
      Potato    Veg
      Orange    Fruit
      Banana    Fruit
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `.loc`:

```
df.loc[df['Item'] == 'Apple', 'Category'] = 'Fruit'
df.loc[df['Item'] == 'Potato', 'Category'] = 'Veg'
```

Output:

```
>>> df
     Item Category
0   Apple    Fruit
1  Potato      Veg
2  Orange    Fruit
3  Banana    Fruit
```

More dynamic version:

```
reps = {
    'Apple': 'Fruit',
    'Potato': 'Veg',
}
df.loc[df['Item'].isin(reps), 'Category'] = df['Item'].replace(reps)
```

Answer (score 1):

Or using [`numpy.select`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.select.html):

```
np.select([df['Item'] == 'Apple', df['Item'] == 'Potato'], ['Fruit', 'Veg'], df['Category'])
```

Or, using a dict:

```
mapping = {
    'Apple': 'Fruit',
    'Potato': 'Veg',
}
df['Category'] = np.select([df['Item'] == k for k in mapping.keys()], [v for v in mapping.values()], df['Category'])
```

Comment: You can also use `np.select`. It's basicaly like a super-`where`: `np.select([df['Item'] == 'Apple', df['Item'] == 'Potato'], ['Fruit', 'Veg'], df['Category'])`

Comment: I didn't know numpy select, but then you can make it a legible oneliner. Thus that seems a good option.